# Order by on a group sum criteria

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

Is it possible to order return rows with a criteria on a sum group ?

For example, my data are :

```
Id     Price     Product     Category
1      12        Book1       Car
2      1         Book2       Art
3      8         Book3       Car
4      7         Book4       Art
5      11        Book5       Car
6      24        Book6       Bridge
```

As the sum of **Car books is 31**, the sum of **Art books is 8** and the sum of **Bridge books is 24**,  I would like to have the following result (Car first, then Bridge and then Art):

```
Id     Price     Product     Category
1      12        Book1       Car
3      8         Book3       Car
5      11        Book5       Car
6      24        Book6       Bridge
2      1         Book2       Art
4      7         Book4       Art
```

On the other hand, I would like to add other Order by criteria (in the example, "Product" criteria).
I have tried many things using ORDER BY and GROUP BY but it always aggregate my results.

Thanks for help !

Comment: why do you want car -> art -> bridge order?

Comment: what are you using to determine the order of the category?  you have car, then art then bridge but that isn't ordered by your sum since art is between car and bridge.

Comment: I made a mistake on the order. It is Sum(Car) > Sum(Bridge) > Sum(Art)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
select 
  l.* from table l
inner join (
  select category, sum(price) as total from table group by category
) r
on l.category = r.category
order by r.total, <some_other_column>
```

This is the procedure I followed:

1. find the subtotals
2. join the original table to the subtotals
3. order the original table by those subtotals

Comment: +1 OP wants `order by r.total DESC, ...` but that's just details.

Comment: +1 I think the group by category in the query for the inner join may also be necessary.